# Getting JsonMappingException for JSON request

Tags: java, json

Can anybody please clarify below query regarding JSON mapping.

We have a field userId as **Long** type and in the JSON request if we pass **String** type value to Long type then we are getting JsonMappingException.

*"Caused by org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.lang.Long from String value 'safdsda': not a valid Long value\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@56ffc7; line: 4, column: 5] "*

where as if it is XML request for the same scenario working fine means the the **String** type value binding to **Long** type and in the service side we are capturing the string value and throwing the relevant Error message.

We have below configuration in the web.xml file to convert Java Objects to JSON and back.

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
```

Can you please let us know do we have to do any  more configuration and why this happening only incase of JSON request not for XML request?

Comment: And how exactly do you intend to parse `"safdsda"` as a `long`??

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply, my only intention is if anyone send wrong values other than Long type then I need to capture wrong value and send the relevant Error message to Consumer, where as in case of XML request for the same scenario working fine.

Comment: You can swallow the JSON itself and make appropriate checks using methods on `JsonNode`; pity that you use Jackson 1.9.x, otherwise you could have used my JSON Schema validator...

Comment: Hi thanks again, Using JsonNode I can do validation at API side but I want bind the wrong value to Long type and in the service end I just want to do validation then throw the exception if it not valid input.

I could have been used your JSON Schema validator but our project is already started long time back and I can't replace now

Comment: Note that there is still a way to use a JSON Schema provided you have a processor converting org.jackson.codehaus to com.fasterxml.jackson ;)

Comment: can you please give us any one example on using com.fasterxml.jackson

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: To move from org.jackson.codehaus to com.fasterxml.jackson where I have to do changes and code side what exactly do we need to do?

Comment: I am afraid you can't "move" from org. to com., since Jersey uses Jackson 1.9.x. You'd have to have both. It is however possible to have both in the classpath and write conversion methods from/to the one to the other. In fact, I have done so for one of my projects, I need to find the code back

Comment: can you please share the code snippet if you find any.